# Document count is same but index size is growing every logstash run

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm sending elasticsearch using the logstash of the data contained in the mysql database.

but each time logstash runs, the number of documents remains the same, but the index size increases.

**first run**
count: 333 **|**
size in bytes : 206kb

**now**
count:333 **|**
size in bytes : 1.6MB

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://***rds.amazonaws.com:3306/"
        jdbc_user => "***"
        jdbc_password => "***"
        jdbc_driver_library => "***\mysql-connector-java-5.1.46/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT id,title,url, FROM tableName"
        schedule => "*/2 * * * *"
    }
}
filter {
  json {
    source => "texts"
    target => "texts"
  }
  mutate { remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ] }
}
output {
    stdout {
            codec => json_lines
    }
    amazon_es {
      hosts => ["***es.amazonaws.com"]
      document_id => "%{id}"
      index => "texts"
      region => "***"
      aws_access_key_id => '***'
      aws_secret_access_key => '***'
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you're always sending the same data over and over. In ES, each time you update a document (i.e. by using the same ID), the older version gets deleted and stays in the index for a while (until the underlying index segments get merged).

Between each run, you can issue the following command:

```
curl -XGET ***es.amazonaws.com/_cat/indices?v
```

In the response you get, check the `docs.deleted` column and you'll see that the number of deleted documents increases.